# Connection could not be established with host mailhog :stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: laravel, mailtrap

I get the above error when I try to send an email from my Laravel 8 Project

Problem:
The Mail_host points to mailtrap in my .env and not mailhog.

.env

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=**************
MAIL_PASSWORD=**************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=admin@*******.sc.ke
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

contact.blade.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Contact;
use Mail; 

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $req)
    {

        $this->validate($req, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'subject' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'subject' => 'required',
            'message' => 'required'
        ]);

        $contact =new Contact;
        $contact->name = $req -> name;
        $contact->email = $req -> email;
        $contact->phone = $req -> phone;
        $contact->subject = $req -> subject;
        $contact->message = $req -> message;

   
        // Toastr::success('Your message has been well received , We will contact you soon');
         $contact->save();

         \Mail::send('client.contact_email',
             array(
                 'name' => $req->get('name'),
                 'email' => $req->get('email'),
                 'subject' => $req->get('subject'),
                 'phone' => $req->get('phone'),
                 'message' => $req->get('message'),
             ), function($message) use ($req)
               {
                  $message->from($req->email);
                  $message->to('abemuchikan@gmail.com');
               });

   
        
        return back()->with('success', 'Hello, '.$contact->name. ' Your  message has been well received.');
    }

   

}
```

I have hosted the files on a shared Cpanel Hosting.
Solution:
I have already cleared the Cache, and also done php artisan optimize.

Answer (score 1):

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.YOUR_DOMAIN.sc.ke
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=user@YOUR_DOMAIN.sc.ke
MAIL_PASSWORD=YOUR_MAIL_PASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 